# How to generate pdf in arabic language in android

Tags: java, android, fonts, itext, itext7

How to add Persian font < if I become successful in adding the font, it will be shown in a messy way

[image: 1]

Comment: Please follow basic StackOverflow guidelines: post the code you have tried, explain the problem you faced. On your screenshot the problem is obviously that Java cannot find the font at the given path

Answer (score 0):

You are providing a relative font file location. Try placing the file inside it or provide the absolute full path as an argument to createFont method